# Get return value of first function invocation match without invoking it twice

Tags: javascript

I have an array of function references.

I need to find the return value of the first function invocation that satisfies my match condition.

How can I avoid calling the matched function twice?

```
var f = function(x) { if (x === 10) return "ten"; }
var g = function(y) { if (y === 20) return "twenty"; }

var result = [f, g].find(m => m(10))
if (result) return result(10)
// this returns "ten"
```

Comment: Can you give some context? What's the 10 for? Where's the array?

Comment: @4castle The array is the array of function references. The `10` is a number.

Comment: So you're trying to find the function where m(10) returns true?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan No, he's trying to get the result of the function call for the function that satisfies the condition.

Comment: @4castle Weird. The question is pretty self-contained; only the title is sub-optimal. It's not relevant what the `10` is *for*, it's the argument being passed to the functions in the array, the array of functions the OP is calling to match against those functions'  return values.

Comment: @DaveNewton: The find will look for a function that returns true when called with 10. Right? The next line will call that same function with a parameter of 10.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Yes. But OP is not trying to find the function, rather the return value of that function (truthy/falsey), but without having to call it twice.

Comment: Not sure if you can do this since `Array.find` returns the item in the array that matches the condition. You'll have to call the function again to get the value of said function. Unless you use some global variables...

Comment: There are any number of ways to do this, but this is probably the easiest. Libraries that would abstract this out would do little different, e.g., with a functional library you could reject non-truthy values and take the first result. IMO just abstract this into a method and be done with it. If the actual methods are long-running then use a simple for-each and return early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure I fully understand you question. It seems to me that you want to iterate through an array of functions and return the result if the function called with the condition is truthy.

```
let fncaller = (fns, condition) => {
  var result
  for (var fn of fns) {
    result = fn(condition)
    if (result) { return result }
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel though. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use global variables?

```js
var f = function(x) {
  return x % 2 == 0
}
var g = function(y) {
  return x % 2 == 1
}

var result = [f, g].find(function(m) {
  window.blah = m(10);
  return window.blah;
})
console.log(window.blah);
```

Or @DaveNewton's method. Not sure which is faster:

```js
var f = function(x) {
  if (x === 10) return "ten";
}
var g = function(y) {
  if (y === 20) return "twenty";
}

var funcs = [f, g];

function checkIt(value) {
  for (var i = 0, numFuncs = funcs.length; i < numFuncs; ++i) {
    var v = funcs[i](value);
    if (v) return v;
  }
}

console.log(checkIt(20));
```

Comment: Seems like standard iteration with an early return would be the most efficient.

Comment: Yeah. Similar effect I would assume since both basically loop through the array. Not sure about performance. Can't check.

Comment: `find` will iterate over *all* functions, though; using simple iteration with an early return wouldn't. Doesn't matter for fast functions or a short list, but for long-running functions it'd matter.

Comment: Oh? I thought `Array.find` would stop at first `true`.

Comment: @DaveNewton: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,910].find(function(x){ console.log(x); return x == 4; })` will stop at 4 and won't check the others...

Comment: Ah, yep, you're right; not sure what I was thinking there.  Rather than a global I'd just shove it into its own function, though, or a closure, or anything, to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Agreed but I wasn't exactly sure what requirements were so I just went with the simplest for now.

Comment: @DaveNewton Using `find` is still possible & there's no reason for anything more than just a regular variable. I used it in my solution and it works like a charm.

Comment: @4castle Yes, that's what I said above ^^ Although a "regular variable" *is* in the global state, which is what IMTheNachoMan and I were discussing.

Comment: @Dave I see a return statement. So this isn't global scope, this is function scope.

Comment: @4castle ... It's returning a global variable. The one in his interpretation of my answer isn't, based on the conversation with the OA.

Answer (score 0):

You could store in a variable as you go. It's better than using a global.

```js
var f = function(x) { if (x === 10) return "ten"; };
var g = function(y) { if (y === 20) return "twenty"; };

function findValue(funcs, val) {
    var result;
    funcs.find(m => result = m(val));
    return result;
}

console.log(findValue([f, g], 10));
```

Comment: That's... a global.

Comment: @Dave The OP was using a return statement, so it's actually function scope.

Comment: @Dave The OP doesn't plan on those statements being in global scope though. This is just a snippet for what should be inside of their function.

Comment: @Dave Okay, I made the answer as clear as I could. It's not a global.

Comment: Nope, now it isn't.